# CSS closest parent rules

Tags: css, sass

As far as I understand, the way CSS works, is that the new rules always take priority over the old ones.
Meaning, if I have:

```
a { color: black }
a { color: white }
```

The `a` tag will be white.

I want this to not take effect, when having a subselector, for example:

```
[dir="ltr"] [text-end] {
    text-align: right;
}
[dir="rtl"] [text-end] {
    text-align: left;
}
```

If the closest parent with a `dir` is `ltr`, `ltr` takes.

However, with this code that is not the case:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <div dir="ltr">
        <div text-end style="width: 100%">
            a
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The text here will be on the `left`, although it is supposed to be `ltr` and be on the `right`.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpKVxp)

Any way I can make it accept the closest parent's style?

Comment: Well, for `ltr` I said I want `text-end` to be `right`, and it is not.Added codepen

Comment: Have you considered using `text-align: end`?

Comment: "_If the closest parent with a dir is ltr, ltr takes._" Can you elaborate.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol while that is very helpful, that is not what I asked precisely. (For this case you are right). I ask, how can I make the closest parent to effect the child

Comment: That's the meaning of the "C" in CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `text-align: inherit;` to `div[text-end]` to inherit `text-align` value from its closet parent. Here is the modified css:

```
div[dir="ltr"] {
  text-align: right;
}

div[dir="rtl"] {
  text-align: left;
}

div[text-end] {
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

```css
div[dir="ltr"] {
  text-align: right;
}

div[dir="rtl"] {
  text-align: left;
}

div[text-end] {
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div dir="rtl">
  <div dir="ltr">
    <div text-end style="width: 100%">
      a
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```